# call listbox change in uwp webview InvokeScriptAsync

Tags: webview, uwp, windows-10

I work with webview in uwp to interact with webpages. Everything works fine except with list box. I call :

```
await Webview.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.getElementsByClassName('select-box')[0].getElementsByTagName('select')[0].selectedIndex = 1;" });
```

The selection is visually change, but the change function of the web page was not called. Means no effect! So i try to fire this call and add (the change listener is on the select-box 0)

```
await Webview.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.getElementsByClassName('select-box')[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true }));" });
        await Webview.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.getElementsByClassName('select-box')[0].getElementsByTagName('select')[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true }));" });
        await Webview.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.getElementsByClassName('select-box')[0].change();" });
        await Webview.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.getElementsByClassName('select-box')[0].getElementsByTagName('select')[0].change();" });
```

None of this 4 lines works.
So i wondered if the change() call is possible?
Any help is welcome.

Comment: What did you mean about 'the change function of the web page'? Could you please provide the HTML page which contains javascript code?

Comment: Change is a jquery event listener function(e) hold by a external js files. Invoke click, keypress, keyup works, but not change event. The listbox are on webpage wich could changed. So i can gave an url, but when you see it maybe the listbox does not appear yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I retry many solution and this time it WORKS !

```
await webView1.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.getElementsByClassName('select-box')[0].getElementsByTagName('select')[0].selectedIndex=1;" });
        await webView1.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.getElementsByClassName('select-box')[0].getElementsByTagName('select')[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true }));" });
```

Didn't find that i'm doing wrong last time, i'm pretty sure that i test this before.
Thanks again Xavier Xie

Answer (score 0):

When I invoke the jquery change method, it will trigger the change event on web page.

I made a simple code sample to test, it worked well on my side.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#select").on('change', function () {
        $("#ptext").text(this.value);
    });
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="select">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>

    <p id="ptext">Write something</p>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<Grid>
    <WebView x:Name="webview" Source="ms-appx-web:///HTMLPage1.html"></WebView>
    <Button Content="call js" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
</Grid>
```

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await webview.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.getElementById('select').selectedIndex=2;$('#select').change();" });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Try $('#select').change(); like your exemple, not a chance throw me a Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020101. Maybe because the list had no Id.